# How can I display an Identity User's roles?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

I want to adjust the _LoginPartial.cshtml to display:

```
Logged in as <username>(<rolename>) | Logoff
```

So I wish to add the first role name associated with the logged in user.

I can't access it via the user object, so how do I access this information?

This is the current code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Logged in as " + User.Identity.GetUserName(), "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the `Role` class, but really what you should be doing is collecting this information together in the controller & passing it, probably in the `ViewBag`. That way your view is abstracted from where you get the username & roles from.

Comment: If Frankie is putting the role name on the _LoginPartial.cshtml then he would have to get the role name in every single controller and place it in the ViewBag. Would it be best to make a base controller or is there a better method?

Comment: Base controller would probably be the best approach

Comment: Another approach instead of moving the aforementioned LoginPartial's logic to a base controller and shoving into ViewBag for every request, is to isolate and have this as a Child Action (in its own controller if you want) and call it via `Html.RenderAction` instead of `Html.Partial`... For extra credit you could even create a specific ViewModel for this and avoid ViewBag altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using claims, then you can downcast the User to a ClaimsPrincipal and then filter the Claims collection on the Type == ClaimsTypes.Role.